# How to change Audacious keyboard controls, preferably to Vim-like?

Tags: linux, vim, xfce

I couldn't find a suitable plugin, there is also nothing in ~/.config/audacious.

What could I possibly do to change controls? For example, I'd like to have the following:

- j - move down the tracklist (only selection, not starting to play
  anything)

  k - move up the tracklist (only selection, not starting to play
  anything)

  h - jump 5 seconds back

  l - jump 5 seconds forward

  J - decrease volume

  K - increase volume

  H - choose previous tab (playlist)

  L - choose next tab (playlist)

Any help appreciated. I use Xubuntu 14.04.

(Besides, I have tried CMus. It's good (especially that it's console-based), but no comfortable multiple playlist management and there are some graphical artifacts at the bottom panel, perhaps because I use it inside a Tmux session)

Comment: Did you try Audacious's forum?

Comment: Somehow I didn't think about that. My bad. However, I've found a great general solution for most, if not all, applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great solution is AutoKey program.

```
sudo apt-get install autokey
```

didn't work for me (Xubuntu 14.04). This did though:

```
sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk
```

After that I was able to reassign the following keys by creating new "Phrases". 
That's my list of phrases (what it does, the hotkey, the command):

```
Play the selected track         p <enter>
Volume down                     d <ctrl>+-
Volume up                       f <ctrl>+<shift>+=
To the first track in the list  g <home>
Jump back 5 secs                h <left>
One item down in the list       j <down>
One item up in the list         k <up>
Jump forward 5 secs             l <right>
To the last track in the list   G <end>
To the previous playlist        H <alt>+<ctrl>+<page_up>
Five items down in the list     J <down><down><down><down><down>
Five items up in the list       K <up><up><up><up><up>
To the next playlist            L <alt>+<ctrl>+<page_down><ctrl>+s
```

Note that in every one of them I've used an option "Window Filter" with value

```
.*Audacious
```

It prevents Autokey from changing behavior of other programs. However, I still had to turn Autokey off while writing this answer - precisely because Firefox window title contains ".*Audacious".